# Using huge pages and DirectByteBuffer in java hotspot jvm on Linux

Tags: java, jvm-hotspot, huge-pages, directmemory

**What I would like to do**

I need to use direct memory to avoid the GC moving things around. I would like to enable huge pages for those.

**So far**

The flag -XX:+UseLargePages works fine when using heap Buffer (non-direct ByteBuffers), but does not work anymore when using DirectByteBuffers.
I have also tried using MappedByteBuffers and a hugetlbfs filesystem. This works but raises a number of issues, so I'm looking for a different solution.

**Config**
CentOS release 6.3, hotspot, jdk1.7

**[EDIT]**

Looking at hotspot source code, they are using a malloc to allocate memory with Unsafe, were shmat/shmget or mmap would be needed to use huge pages.

**[EDIT] Why non heap memory**

We are in a NUMA context, for an in memory database, with a lot of long lived objects. The JVM does not partition the old gen when the UseNUMA flag is on. Using direct memory allows us to have the memory stay close to the threads that needs it.

Benchmarking took obviously a huge role in the decision to use DirectByteBuffers. I'm **not** asking whether I should be using DirectByteBuffer or not, I'm rather looking for an answer to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested, the link to the [oracle bug report](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8021829)

The link to the corresponding [openJDK ticket](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8021829). Closed as won't fix so far.
On Linux the THP feature might help, even-though it comes with its own bunch of issues.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a benchmark which unequivocably shows that GC relocation is a bottleneck for your application?

If not, DO NOT DO THIS.

If so, please add a link to it so it can be peer-reviewed.

These sorts of low-level effects are notoriously difficult to isolate as the cause of performance problems, and it is very possible to waste a lot of time chasing phantom effects & producing a solution which tries to bypass the JVM & only results in far worse performance than would have been obtained if you stuck the well-trodden path.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround is to use JNI to allocate the memory in C using whatever method you'd like and return a ByteBuffer. See [NewDirectByteBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#NewDirectByteBuffer). This approach has the added benefit that you can deterministically free the memory as well.